# Difference betweent this.argument and argument?

Tags: javascript

I call the object methods below like this.

```
new Cout( elem1 ).load( 'body' )

new COut( elem1 ).display( 'email' )
```

I only use one instance at a time. Because I only use one instance at a time, I want to remove `this.element` and use the passed in `element` instead.

This got me to wondering is the passed in element static or instance based.  I think it might be this.element ( instance based )...even when I don't explicitly state it.  I plan on removing all mentions of this.element for just element.

Is it?

Note: this is returned implicitly if no other return is given.

```
var COut = function ( element ) 
{
    var messages = 
    {
        name:         'Please enter a valid name',
        email:        'Please enter a valid email',
        email_s:      'Please enter a valid email.',
        pass:         'Please enter password, 6-40 characters',
        url:          'Please enter a valid url',
        title:        'Please enter a valid title',
        tweet:        'Please enter a valid tweet',
        empty:        'Please complete all fields',
        same:         'Please make emails equal',
        taken:        'Sorry, that email is taken',
        validate:     'Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:fo@foo.com">support</a> to reset your password'
    };
    this.element = element;
    this.display = function( type ) 
    {
        this.element.innerHTML = messages[ type ];
    };
    this.load = function( location )
    {
        new AjaxRequest().invoke( 'ajax_type=async_load', function( response_text )
        {
            document[location].innerHTML = response_text;  
            new Cin().init( response_text.charAt( 6 ) ); // Correlate this point to Ajax Call.
        } ); 
    };
};
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, but how `this` works [is described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Look at these 4 cases...and you will see that this.element behaves like element....http://www.jsfiddle.net/5yAJa/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`element` isn't really either. It's a local variable to the constructor that will be defined per call. It's only a property of `this` because it's been set explicitly:

```
var COut = function ( element ) 
{
    // ...
    this.element = element;
    // ...
};
```

Still, using it rather than `this.element` should work fine with any function/method defined within the constructor:

```
var COut = function ( element ) 
{
    // ...
    this.display = function( type ) 
    {
        element.innerHTML = messages[ type ];
    };
    // ...
};
```

Where it won't be accessible is if you instead used the `prototype` to define methods outside of the constructor. Here, `element` wouldn't be in scope; but `this` would be, so `this.element` would be as well:

```
COut.prototype.display = function ( type ) {
     this.element.innerHTML = messages[ type ];

     element.innerHTML = messages[ type ]; // ERROR: `element` is not defined
};
```

Comment: I'm assuming that b.c. I pass it in through the constructor element is actually this.element...I will run a jfiddle.net test...just a sec.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist The arguments of a constructor don't automatically or implicitly become properties of `this`. That has to be done explicitly with lines such as: `this.element = element;`

Comment: I don't think you are correct..view this fiddle...this.element...behaves the sames as element

Comment: They are the same...can you show me an instance of where they behave differently?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist Yes, within the constructor, they will behave the same. My point was simply that `element` is restricted to the constructor and only functions defined within the constructor, where as `this.element` won't be: http://jsfiddle.net/coiscir/RHQAh/1/

Comment: O.K...this is the model I use.

Comment: Why would I use .prototype outside the constructor...when I could just use this.functionName inside the function?  It keeps my instance functions enclosed in brackets?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist There are pros and cons to either option. One of the main benefits to using the `prototype` object is that you only define 1 function for the method. Within the constructor, it has to redefine the method with each call, adding (usually unnecessarily) to the memory consumed by your application. But, for scope constraints, such as the one you're asking about, defining them within the constructor may be beneficial or even necessary.

Comment: Is there a way to write a fiddle to prove this...it is hard to believe...it would re-define these functions each call.

Comment: Yeah. Test if the methods are equal between 2 instances: http://jsfiddle.net/coiscir/cqChh/. As `Function`s aren't primitives, they'll be compared by reference (i.e., by memory location) rather than similarity.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `this` it becomes *member* of the class you need to instantiate using `new` keyword otherwise there is no point of using `this` without creating instance of a class.

Also anything you set via `this` becomes instance member which means it is added to each signature of instance you create. You can avoid that by using `prototype` property instead.

Comment: but the argument that I construct it with must be bound to this anyways...correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `this` and just refer to `element` within the function, then it will refer to the `element` that you pass in the arguments.

You're using `new` every time you reference your object but I think this is wrong. Each instance will have no knowledge of the previous properties you've put on `this` and you'll have to pass in the same element each time (which is what you're doing but there's no need to if you just save the object when you first instantiate it).

That's what `new` does - gives you a clean object for `this`.

I think what you want is something like this:

```
var c = new Cout(some_element);
c.display();
```

if you save element as a property of this in the constructor, then when you call `c.display()` it will be able to access `this.element` just fine.

Comment: I'm assuming that b.c. I pass it in through the constructor element is actually this.element...I will run a jfiddle.net test...just a sec.